# Exporting QGIS layer to Gephi

Tags: qgis, export, csv

When trying to export a QGIS multistring line layer to Gephi through a CSV file it gives the error that the CSV is lacking Source and Target attributes in the layer. Since there is already a similar question out there, and having tried their solutions (using AequilibraE, and Qchainage, both of which give out Python errors), I was wondering if there is an alternative solution out there.